# Vue @change should update database

Tags: express, vue.js, checkbox

I'm creating a todolist and trying to make my checkbox change a property both in vue and in  my DB. The checkbox should change the active status to true if box is checked, and to false if set to unchecked.

[Vue HTML the v-model change the "active" property. @change should call the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33AAW.png)

```html
 <label> active task:  </label> <input type="checkbox"  
     @change="updateActive(todo.id)" v-model="todo.active">
```

[The function. If the checkbox is changed from check to uncheck, change the active status to false, vice versa. The error says that e is undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMF1A.png)

```js
    updateActive: function (e){
    if(e.target.checked){

        let url = "/update-task1?active=" + true + "&id=" + id
        fetch(url, {
            method: "PUT",

        })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('error', error)
            }),
            this.fetchData();

    } else {

        let url = "/update-task1?active=" + false + "&id=" + id
        fetch(url, {
            method: "PUT",

        })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('error', error)
            }),
            this.fetchData();

    }
},
```

[Express to update the task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBwri.png)

```js
app.put('/update-task', function (req, res) {
let collection = 'tasks'
MongoClient.connect(url,
    { useUnifiedTopology: true },
    function (err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;

        let completed = req.query.completed;
        let query = parseInt(req.query.id);
        let completedNewValue = { $set: { 'completed': completed } };
        let updateItem = { 'id': query };
        let databaseobject = db.db("agiledb");

        databaseobject.collection(collection).updateOne(updateItem, completedNewValue),
            function (err, res) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("active");
                db.close();
            };
    });
    });
```

[Property being created in addTodo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhgUG.png)

```js
    methods: {
    addTodo: function ({target}) {
        if(this.newTodo.trim().length == 0){
            return
        } else {
            console.log("wack")
            this.todos.push({
                id: Date.now(),
                title: this.newTodo,
                created: true,
                active: false,
                completed: false,
                editing: false,
                assigned: this.newAssigned,
            });
            axios.post('/todo', {
                id: Date.now(),
                title: this.newTodo,
                created: true,
                active: false,
                completed: false,
                editing: false,
                assigned: this.newAssigned,
            })
```

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

You either use passed `todo.id` or pass an event itself in addition to `todo.id`:

```
@change="updateActive($event, todo.id)"
```

```
updateActive: function (e, todoId){
...
}
```

Comment: You passed `todo.id` but in `updateActive` you expect the event object. That means you should either pass `$event` instead of `todo.id` or pass them bothif you need both in `updateActive`

Comment: Okay. now i have: updateActive: function (e, todo.id). but im getting errors on the todo.id.
And when is tries to change the data it says that: "id is not defined" so it can't fetch the task anymore i guess.

Comment: Can you update code in your post with all these changes?

Comment: The issue now i think, is that it can't find the id value anymore

  updateActive: function (e){
    if(e.target.checked){

        let url = "/update-task1?active=" + true + "&id=" + id   <----- Cant find this one anymore.

When it worked i had an @click on the checkbox that would start the function, but that meant i couldn't set it to false in database, only in vue

Comment: You didn't changed `updateActive` definition to `updateActive: function (e, todoId){`. That way you can use `todoId` as `id`

Comment: so like this:    

`updateActive: function (e, todoId) {
        if(e.target.checked){

            let url = "/update-task1?active=" + true + "&id=" + todoId
            fetch(url, {
                method: "PUT",

            })`

Comment: Yes, exactly. Keep in mind that `$event` is a special prop to get all event props to be able to pass them in a event handler along with other params.

Comment: Okay. It still behaves weird though. When i click the checkboxes they wont change for about 4 clicks. After that they stop being buggy and i can change every checkbox like i should. The database though is not updated for all of them only the first one.

Comment: check what you got in `e` after every click

Comment: What do you mean with in e, anatoly?

Comment: You get two params here `function (e, todoId)`. So I speak about the first one `e`